# Control playback via Keypad in Android Tv

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-tv, exoplayer, key-events

I am playing a video.It is playing for android TV.So We have to control it via keypad.Now the problem is We are not able to control the prev,next,play button via  Key pad.We are able to handle the seek bar of the player using the following code:

```
 mAdUiContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                try {
                    if (mediaController != null)
                        mediaController.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

//We are using exo player here,Now I have to handle the key event and I am not getting what to do next..As I am getting no idea.

Comment: Are you using `Lean back` library for your TV app ?

Comment: Yes.I am using it.

Comment: Then they have the default `PlayBack Overlay Activity` for playing videos why you are using exo player ?

Comment: For adding VideoPlayerWithAdPlayback we have used exo player

Comment: Did you find any solution? @Mainak